# Python equation answer is incorrect

Tags: math, python-3.6

I am making a program that calculates trajectory but when running the code the answer to the equation is far to small but when the same is run on a calculator the answer is fine.

so far I have tried every thing I can think of such as using the fraction module to try and resolve it:

The equation:

```
D= 9.81/V^2*sin(2*angle)
```

The python equation:

```
D=9.81/((200**2)*math.sin(2*10))
```

The target answer is 708

The current answer 0.00026836.....

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
angle = 10*math.pi/180.0
D=9.81/((200**2)*math.sin(2*angle))
```

Python, like C, C++, Java, and JavaScript, uses radians for trig functions, not degrees.